# cocos2dx v3.9 integration with facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to integrate facebook in my game on cocos2dx v3.9, but I have a problem. Could you help me please? 
So let me describe my actions step by step :

1) I have downloaded sdkbox  [from sdkbox official site](http://www.sdkbox.com/plugins/facebook#versions)

2) I have created new Application [on dev facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/)

note:
 - I create basic setup
 - I have done app available for all ( green dot is near  name my app )
 - in settings click on add platform - Android
 - download openssl and executed command in terminal :
   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 
so copy the sequence of symbols in buffer 
 - open Browser and paste from buffer to key-hash field the sequence symbols
 - Then fill the package name (class name left blank) and click save open alert dialog with next text

> Google Play Package Name
>
> There was a problem verifying the package name org.cocos.CocosProject on Google Play. Please check the package name and try again.
>   If your app isn't listed publicly on Google Play yet you can ignore this message.

So My app isn't listed publicly on Google Play and I click Use this package name

3) After that I go in command line, open directory where is my game :
and setup facebook sdkbox :

- sdkbox import facebook - and I get output with error(do not patch AppDelegate.cpp ( I survey the problem and seems it is because I have changed containing AppDelegate.cpp) It seems ok, I continue setup)
- in proj.android/res/values/strings.xml I add new line with

  My_FACEBOOK_APP_ID
- and in file proj.android/AndroidManifest.xml  replace _replace_with_your_app_id_ with my Facebook App ID
- And in proj.android/project.properties and change target to target=android-15

I compile my project.
after that content of  proj.android/project.properties :

target=android-15

android.library.reference.1=libs/facebook_lib/

So when I run app on android it crash with such error (from adb logcat)

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/org.cocos.Test-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/org.cocos.Test-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5100)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4680)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4613)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:162)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/org.cocos.Test-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/org.cocos.Test-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5085)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3322):    ... 12 more
```

Could you help me please! Thank you for any idea and any useful links.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.cocos.Test" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <application hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="cocos2dcpp" />
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderMY_FB_APP_ID" android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" />
    </application>
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

**UPDATE** I did not publish my app on facebook, and maybe my package name is not unique

**UPDATE** How I have created app on facebook
1)go on https://developers.facebook.com/ and create new app with basic setup, fill display name and email, and select type - game.and click create app id
2) so next I go on App review and published app (after that green dot near of my app) 
3) so please Attention, next step is absolute foggy for me, I open settings click add platform, select android, go to theterminal enter next command

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and I get sequence symbols and enter in key hash so and fill field with my name package google play. and click save.

**UPDATE**

What is wrong in my steps ? Any idea?

Useful links :

- [sdk box plugin page](http://www.sdkbox.com/plugins/facebook)
- [Getting Started With The SDKBOX Facebook Plugin](http://blog.cocos2d-x.org/2015/08/getting-started-with-the-sdkbox-facebook-plugin/)
- [Facebook Integration Guide](http://docs.sdkbox.com/en/plugins/facebook/v3-cpp/)

Comment: Can you show manifest?

Comment: @Striker Thank you for attention, I updated my post.

Comment: Have you set up the app on facebook? You dont need it published for testing; just linked.

Comment: yes I  have done it,  Updated My post with step by step describe how i created  app on facebook.

Comment: Try build for latest target

Comment: You say about last version cocos ? 
or sdkbox ?
thanks for reply.

Comment: Change Android target to the latest

Comment: I try change  target as 
target=android-21
 but it is not working

Comment: Set android:exported="false" and try. You will have to change it back on release.

Answer (score 0):

So Please Check Build.xml in proj.android in bottom file, there is must be path to all *.jar files Example

```
<target name="-pre-compile">
        <!-- Redefine project.all.jars.path before -compile executes -->
        <path id="project.all.jars.path">
            <fileset file="./jars/*.jar" />
            <fileset file="./jars/facebook_lib/bin/*.jar" />
            <fileset file="./jars/facebook_lib/libs/*.jar" />
            <fileset file="${sdk.dir}/tools/support/*.jar" />
        </path>
    </target>
```

So right now game is starting without crash.